# Loading Data To Appended Row In Form Using Ajax & Json

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

OK, I have a table where the users can append a row as follows:

```
// Append New Row To Email Change Form //
$(function () {
var count = 1000;
$('#AddRow').click(function () {
    $('table.subgrid tbody').append('<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="delete[]" value="No">No</td><td><input type="text" name="customernumber[]" id="' + count + '_cust" onChange="ajax_customer_info(' + count + ')" maxlength="6" /></td><td><span id="' + count + '_name"></span></td><td><select name="type[]"><option value="A">ACH</option><option value="C">Credit</option><option value="I">Invoice</option><option value="S">Statement</option></select></td><td><select name="deliverymethod[]"><option value="E">Electronic</option><option value="P">Print</option></select></td><td><input size="40" type="text" class="fieldname" maxlength="50" name="newemailaddress[]" /><input type="hidden" name="oldemailaddress[]" /><input type="hidden" name="companyid[]" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="action[]" value="add" /></td></tr>');
    count++;
});
```

});

Within this row they can enter a customer number which through ajax should return the customer name automatically.  Here is the ajax:

```
function ajax_customer_info(row) {
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp!=null) {
    var url="/hq/servlet/customerinfo";
    url=url+"?customernumber="+document.getElementById(row+"_cust").value;
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(row) {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete") {
            xmlDoc=xmlHttp.responseXML;
            var data = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById(row+"_name").innerHTML=data.name;
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
}
```

The problem is this doesn't populate the customer name.  I noticed if I remove the row+ in this:

```
document.getElementById(row+"_name").innerHTML=data.name;
```

And replace it with say ("name") and of course change the corresponding id to that in the appended row it works.  However, I need unique id's as the user can append multiple rows.  Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here??  Thanks!

Comment: why are you using a custom ajax method when you already have jQuery on your page, which has the excellent $.ajax() function ready for use?

Comment: I don't know if that is the cause of your problem, but your id attribute should not start with a number.  It must start with a character.  So try to give the element an id of `id="cust_' + count + '"`

Comment: @Dogoku Good question, and the only answer I have for you is that I'm fairly new to ajax in general and am not keen to all of the best practices.  I will look into it.  If you feel like it, could you give me an example of how you would have implemented the above functionality using the $.ajax function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a parameter `row` to your ajax on ready state function, this will be used instead of the row value you passed to `ajax_customer_info`. Therefore use `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()` instead of `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(row)`

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thanks Musa!